# find one meter to scale in earth heightmap

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, heightmap

I have a heightmap that scales from 0 to 255. the map is only for elevation (discluding water and ice) what would be the appropriate way to calculate the scale of one meter? heightmap below
[image: earth heigtmap]

Comment: Apparently the image was produced by the process described here: https://grabcad.com/tutorials/how-to-3d-print-a-detailed-accurate-model-of-the-earth - And while you can check the scale and resolution of the originals, the following step is a problem "I altered the contrast so that the mountains were less pronounced compared to the rest of the land". I strongly suggest you produce the final image yourself if you want accuracy. The originals are available at https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/73934/topography and https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/73963/bathymetry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the final image came from [this tutorial](https://grabcad.com/tutorials/how-to-3d-print-a-detailed-accurate-model-of-the-earth) (as suggested in the comments), which in turn used these [topography](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/73934/topography) & [bathymetry](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/73963/bathymetry) resources there's a few things that need to be addressed.

First, the tutorial states:

> For the topography map, I altered the contrast so that the mountains
> were less pronounced compared to the rest of the land.

That means that some of the original information for the elevations above sea level is lost. Specifically, some slopes will be steeper than indicated by the original data.

Next:

> ... I used Gimp’s Alpha Separation tool to make sure the sea layer
> occupied the lower 50% of the grayscale tones, and the land layer the
> upper 50% (so the sea would definitely map to indentations rather than
> outward features)

This means that 50% represents sea level in the final image. Everything below 50% is underwater while everything above 50% is above.

This complicates the scale because bathymetry portion of the image was originally scaled from -8000m to 0m while the topography portion was scaled from 0m to 6400m. The total data range is -8000m to 6400m. But 50% of that range isn't sea level! To deal with this, we need to normalize the lower & upper values separately and map each back onto its respective range. Assuming a 0 to 255 pixel representation, the elevation scale would be something like this:

```
data = pixel / 255;
if (data <= .5)
   return (1-(data / .5)) * -8000;
else
   return ((data / .5) - 1) * 6400;
```

Note: it's probably a good idea to guard the divisions in order to ensure the intermediate results have been bounded to the 0 to 1 range.

The final consideration is:

> I did some manual editing with the paintbrush tool to remove any
> remaining black lines around the continents. This gave a smoother
> shading for coastal shelves so that these gradually disappeared
> beneath the ocean layer rather than dropping down abruptly.

Again, this means that some of the data represented in the image isn't going to match the original source data.

To echo the suggestion in the comments: if you want accuracy, I would strongly recommend starting with the source data and creating your own composite image.

Comment: I did reverse image search before posting the comment on the question. And if found various very similar - if not identical - images. Some behind a price tag. And attribution not always clear. It seems they all come from the same source data, directly or indirectly, but for most result we have less detail on the process to produce the image compared with the linked tutorial. Which leaves us with even less confidence about how to interpret them. So, while I cannot guarantee the image is form the tutorial, it is both the best bet to interpret it, and an starting guide for OP to make their own.

Comment: I think your conclusions are as confident as we can hope for under the present circumstances. Ideally, OP would edit to include that information in the question directly. You make a good point about including a guide to help readers make their own composite map from the source material.